# Stop and rm old docker container and start new with Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hi I'm using GitLab CI on my Spring Boot application

This is what I want to do : 
- execute my test
- build the app
- dockerize it and remove the old container

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
image: maven:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - release
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test

project-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package

release:
  image: docker:git
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  stage: release
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --tag=$IMAGE_TAG . --pull -t $IMAGE_NAME
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
  only:
    - master

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  image: gitlab/dind:latest
  cache: {}
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  before_script:
    # add the server as a known host
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}"
    # stop container, remove image.
    - ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker stop ${IMAGE_TAG}" || true
    - ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rm ${IMAGE_TAG}" || true
    - ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rmi -f ${IMAGE_NAME}" || true
    # start new container
    - ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker run --publish=8080:8080 -d ${IMAGE_NAME}"
  only:
    - master
```

But the docker stop and docker rm/rmi lines does not work. Here is the stack trace :

```
108 $ ssh-keyscan -H $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
109 # MY_SERVER_IP SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
110 # MY_SERVER_IP SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
111 $ ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}"
112 WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
113 WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/deployer/.docker/config.json.
114 Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
115 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
116 Login Succeeded
117 $ ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rm -f ${IMAGE_NAME} 2>/dev/null || exit 0"
118 $ ssh $DEPLOYER_USER@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker run --publish=8080:8080 -d ${IMAGE_NAME}"
119 0ff2aeeb0bf19b3c528dacaf2f8e6022587c1f3b4d845c1c583731eb76c1b65b
120 docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pedantic_lamarr (96dd544514d257320160c15adb1b4c0f4a91c7423e20643ea901774d1528c4f1): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated.
122
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/name=systemd': Operation not permitted
```

So to sum up : the 3 first jobs works but if I have a container running in my server, the last one fail because I can't stop and remove the old container

Any idea ?